# Area of a circumscribed circle given sidelengths of inscribed triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

The sides of a triangle have legths of 7, 15, and 20. What is the exact area of the circumscribed circle?

Comment: `My ` There is a clickable "*edit*" button right below your post. Use it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was going to add on more to the problem but decided not to. But if you could please try to sound less condescending I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you look at the FAQ about homework we ask to see what you have tried and where you are stuck.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Other_properties) has a formula if you just want an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. I really would, but this is an entity separate from my homework, and I had no idea where to start. Thanks again!

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer Sorry if that sounded condenscending, but you've been around for long enough to know the expectations of providing some context and showing some effort.

Comment: Please research your problem before posting.  The circumscribed circle of a triangle has a center, which is called the circumcenter.  A search for that term at Math.SE or on the world wide web will produce a characterization for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$
a=7, \quad b=15, \quad c=20.
$$
By the law of cosines, 
$$
a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c \cos A, 
$$
so 
$$
\cos A = \frac{b^2 + c^2-a^2}{2 b c} = {24\over25}, \qquad \sin A = \sqrt{1-\cos^2A} = {7\over25}
$$
From the law of sines, we can find the circumradius $R$:
$$
{a\over\sin A} = {b\over\sin B} = {c\over\sin C} = 2R \quad\Rightarrow\quad
R = {a\over2\sin A}=12.5
$$
So  the area of the circumscribed circle is
$$
\pi R^2 = \pi \left( {a\over2\sin A} \right)^2 = {625\over4}\pi.
$$